# Need help breaking down JSON string in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, string

I need to be able to grab some data from a string using PHP.
I got an API from the games website and need to break it down.
The string I need to break down is this:
    http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1513

I need to get the small icon image from that string which is the first url in the string, and the current price, which in the string is 887.
So, where it states this:

**"current":{"trend":"neutral","price":887}**

I need to grab the 887 and put it into a variable.

I'm using PHP,
thanks in advance if anyone can help :)

Comment: `json_decode()`??? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this purpose:

```
$item  = json_decode($json)->item;

$price = $item->current->price;
$icon  = $item->icon;
```

Comment: You can set `json_decode`'s second argument to true to render it as a `associative array`

Comment: @Mouser And what gain would I get by doing that in this situation?

Comment: Nothing, just wanted to mention it. Pretty useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

Download the JSON and convert to an object.

```
$item = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=1513'))->item;
$name = $item->name;
// etc.
```

Here's a function you should keep handy.  It is useful for printing formatted objects and arrays, which makes it much easier to examine their structures.

```
function debug($v) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($v);
    echo '</pre>';  
}
```

Comment: Absolute legend Dave, thank you very much!!